TV series based in Ancient Rome
I remember watching a TV series based in Ancient Rome a long time ago and can't remember its name. Here's what I can recall:
It was about a rich blond girl and her Friends, and I believe they solve mysteries or something. In the beginning of the series the rich girl buys an African slave her age, who becomes her best friend. They find the girl'a older brother later in the series, when one of their friends gets into a bind at a coliseum, the slave's brother is a slave gladiator. Due to certain circumstances the brother is given the opportunity to be set free, but instead chooses to remain a gladiator in order to earn money, and promises to come back for his sister when he has enough to support the two of them.
Their other friends were two or three boys. One was a poor boy who dived for money, the other was a rich but kind boy like the blond, who was studying to be a doctor or something.
Some additional things that I can recall is that the rich girl's mother is dead and she was visiting her grave, which I believe was the time she met her friend who dives for money. I think he tried to steel from her.
Could someone please tell me what it's called? I think it might be called Pompeii or something, but I've been unable to find it for ages and I would really like to see it again. Thank you.
EDIT: I watched it about three to four years ago, while it was being released, it was in english and was live action (not a cartoon). The main characters were teenagers.

You should when did you watch it, and the language.

I think this is likely to be Roman Mysteries (2007 - 2008)



IMDB

Follows four children in Ancient Rome who solve a number of exciting, dangerous and challenging mysteries.

Wikipedia

Roman Mysteries is a television series based on the series of children's historical novels by Caroline Lawrence.
The books take place in the ancient Roman Empire during the reign of the Emperor Titus. They detail the adventures of four children who solve mysteries and have adventures in Ostia, Rome, Greece, and beyond: Flavia, a Roman girl who lives in Ostia; Nubia, a slave girl from Africa; Jonathan, a Jewish boy; and Lupus, a mute beggar boy.


That's it! Thank you so much!
